# Extra 0 byte at end of MemoText String

Tags: stellar-sdk, java-sdk, xdr

I extracted a [TransactionEnvelope XDR](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAAEMy3%2FN735%2BS8%2FjcLYweVCmRxnN2QqWCvGGbxlhX5v3AAAAZAB4Dl4AAAADAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAXSGkgWnksIGhlcmVzIGFuIGFuZ3BhbyEAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAK5TNRH%2BgV9qHLIuWk99Epe7OYH6l7cSXKW18R9DFoIDAAAAAAAAAAAAmJaAAAAAAAAAAAFhX5v3AAAAQHx9LVy0EsDozAxndsy%2BD6E2bWmTAMmnhLoFqf2FfoRAMXjC9BW16ZQlOR%2BwWH5PSKnz22QpAxY4gMkJvH8LCwQ%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test) several months ago for testing. It parses fine in the lab and the SDKs.

I've tried parsing it by hand and there's something I don't understand. After the MemoText is finished, the next item should be an int (4 bytes) count of operations. The next 4 bytes are `0, 0, 0, 0`, indicating that there's zero operations. But there is actually 1 operation. As the fifth byte is `1`, and the bytes that follow it decode to that single operation, it seems that there's an extra `0` byte between the Memo and the operation count.

It's not a string terminator, because [the en/decoding of strings](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/xdr/XdrDataOutputStream.java#L17-L21) clearly uses 4 bytes to count the number of bytes in the string, followed by that quantity of bytes and no trailing bytes.

It's not a Memo terminator, because [there isn't one](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/xdr/Memo.java#L68-L69). And it doesn't separate the Transaction data from the operation list, because [there's no such separator](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/xdr/Transaction.java#L100-L102).

The extra weird bit is when I debug the Java SDK's parsing of this, I can see the extra `0` in the buffer, but when it comes to parse the operation count, this extra byte is "magically" skipped. I can't find the code that is reading it.

Here's the Java SDK parsing code that I used for debugging:

```
Network.useTestNetwork();

String sample = "AAAAAHN2/eiOTNYcwPspSheGs/HQYfXy8cpXRl+qkyIRuUbWAAAFeAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYPAuntzs/lk6C+6JkakdDhc5zXww5d6mPBdFK+c3FQAAAACVAvkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALE0VmAhfAS7Juzrcn3ZJ8q6XTRMsAztEdYPxjUNGlN+AAAAAlQL5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC87zZTiuFN3kMO5HLufFatDo63xg/2ve3ivM4Jh4iM8wAAAAJUC+QAAAAAAQAAAACxNFZgIXwEuybs63J92SfKul00TLAM7RHWD8Y1DRpTfgAAAAoAAAAYbGlmZV91bml2ZXJzZV9ldmVyeXRoaW5nAAAAAQAAAAI0MgAAAAAAAQAAAAC87zZTiuFN3kMO5HLufFatDo63xg/2ve3ivM4Jh4iM8wAAAAoAAAAGZmVudG9uAAAAAAABAAAAB0ZFTlRPTiEAAAAAAQAAAAC87zZTiuFN3kMO5HLufFatDo63xg/2ve3ivM4Jh4iM8wAAAAoAAAAGZmVudG9uAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAABg8C6e3Oz+WToL7omRqR0OFznNfDDl3qY8F0Ur5zcVAAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAACxNFZgIXwEuybs63J92SfKul00TLAM7RHWD8Y1DRpTfgAAAAYAAAACQWFyZHZhcmsAAAAAAAAAAAGDwLp7c7P5ZOgvuiZGpHQ4XOc18MOXepjwXRSvnNxUAAAAAAX14QAAAAABAAAAALE0VmAhfAS7Juzrcn3ZJ8q6XTRMsAztEdYPxjUNGlN+AAAABgAAAAJCZWF2ZXIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYPAuntzs/lk6C+6JkakdDhc5zXww5d6mPBdFK+c3FQAAAAABfXhAAAAAAEAAAAAsTRWYCF8BLsm7OtyfdknyrpdNEywDO0R1g/GNQ0aU34AAAAGAAAAAkNoaW5jaGlsbGEAAAAAAAABg8C6e3Oz+WToL7omRqR0OFznNfDDl3qY8F0Ur5zcVAAAAAAF9eEAAAAAAQAAAAABg8C6e3Oz+WToL7omRqR0OFznNfDDl3qY8F0Ur5zcVAAAAAYAAAACQ2hpbmNoaWxsYQAAAAAAAHN2/eiOTNYcwPspSheGs/HQYfXy8cpXRl+qkyIRuUbWAAAAAAX14QAAAAABAAAAAAGDwLp7c7P5ZOgvuiZGpHQ4XOc18MOXepjwXRSvnNxUAAAABwAAAACxNFZgIXwEuybs63J92SfKul00TLAM7RHWD8Y1DRpTfgAAAAJBYXJkdmFyawAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAABg8C6e3Oz+WToL7omRqR0OFznNfDDl3qY8F0Ur5zcVAAAAAcAAAAAsTRWYCF8BLsm7OtyfdknyrpdNEywDO0R1g/GNQ0aU34AAAACQ2hpbmNoaWxsYQAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAYPAuntzs/lk6C+6JkakdDhc5zXww5d6mPBdFK+c3FQAAAABAAAAALE0VmAhfAS7Juzrcn3ZJ8q6XTRMsAztEdYPxjUNGlN+AAAAAkFhcmR2YXJrAAAAAAAAAAABg8C6e3Oz+WToL7omRqR0OFznNfDDl3qY8F0Ur5zcVAAAAAAAAAIrAAAAAAAAAASHiIzzAAAAQE00K8gytC2tLc9ZNgbg5soLJxHwRuPQYIcFoEh7XA36HFPnn0adM1ytn7NF+lSc0Cuoutaaj3pgvrFfuhpZ9gUNGlN+AAAAQGzSbbChPW/f1jADXSCuDpNunHSI95Na46O8tsIWmBjdipzFZeuV2v+sgmwqjeaFE48f4VtPzULtMSR7Y8mPgAWvnNxUAAAAQMNCi/yq4becgE9Dc5XYXKu6aGfa55/jNxANPefE5e+B1n5fYWftfX/we6fEduXTTEIoHiNpsVsw7O0nouI54w0RuUbWAAAAQF4UP8Pq6xXhOOzlF3iX5nvQh5AX8+aXjq4rwzpEaTCpFCVgstD+R5qXyRq/Nyywm/JDV5nU6rbRLFciMP2r/wc=";

Transaction.fromEnvelopeXdr(sample);
```

And this is my console output where I'm parsing the data manually, 1 field at a time:

```
@ s.drop(60).take(23)
res128: Array[Byte] = Array(72, 105, 32, 90, 121, 44, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 115, 32, 97, 110, 32, 97, 110, 103, 112, 97, 111, 33)

@ new String(res128)
res129: String = "Hi Zy, heres an angpao!"

@ s.drop(83).take(5)
res130: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

You can see that after the String of the Memo is parsed, the subsequent bytes are `0,0,0,0,1` and not `0,0,0,1` as expected.

My question can be framed in a number of different ways, but the underlying question is the same. Why does this XDR parse OK when it has this extra `0`? Why is there an extra `0` when the encoder doesn't write one? Why does the decoder ignore the extra `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is the extra padding bytes set so that the length is a multiple of 4. From the [RFC 4506](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506#page-10) (a.k.a. the XDR Spec):

> The standard defines a string of n (numbered 0 through n-1) ASCII
> bytes to be the number n encoded as an unsigned integer (as described
> above), and followed by the n bytes of the string.  Byte m of the
> string always precedes byte m+1 of the string, and byte 0 of the
> string always follows the string's length.  **If n is not a multiple of
> four, then the n bytes are followed by enough (0 to 3) residual zero
> bytes, r, to make the total byte count a multiple of four.**

In this case, the string is 23 bytes long and so we have one extra byte of padding.